# how to select multiple rows using jquery

Tags: jquery

hello everyone
how to select multiple cell from table using jquery . i dont want to use any plugin for this.
i have to two tables which are dynamically generated.

Comment: You need to get a little bit more specific. What are the criterias you want to query for ?

Comment: [Just select?](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector)

Comment: this is difficult to answer without a proper example of the table layout. you just need to write proper jquery selectors.

Comment: Whats your criteria for selection?

Comment: actually i have retrieved certain dimensions and measures in 2 tables and now i want select one or more dimension and one or measures and then send these values to server using jquery.  i just need the help on how to select multiple cell so that i can combine them and then use them

Comment: sorry for not providing enough info..but all i wanted was to select cells using click.

Answer (score 0):

try [jQuery Delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for dOM using parent selector

> Description: Attach a handler to one
>   or more events for all elements that
>   match the selector, now or in the
>   future, based on a specific set of
>   root elements.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a common class to the rows, for example `class="myclass"`, then in jQuery:

```
$("myclass").dosomething;
```

Make sense?